# Direct assignment to the reverse side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use category.set() instead

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite, django-rest-framework

a problem on M2M Django assignment

this is where i get the error :

```
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.title = validated_data.get('title', instance.title)
        instance.category = validated_data.get('category', instance.category)
        instance.price = validated_data.get('price', instance.price)
        instance.description = validated_data.get('description', instance.description)
        instance.image = validated_data.get('image', instance.image)
        instance.active = validated_data.get('active', instance.active)
        instance.deleted = validated_data.get('deleted', instance.deleted)
        instance.parent_category.set(validated_data.get('parent_category'))
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

i tried "add" method too but it gets same error

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the field "category" is a ManyToManyField and you are trying to directly assign a value to it.

You can try replacing the line with:

```
instance.category.set(validated_data.get('category', instance.category))
```

If you don't want to replace the category but add a new one you can try:

```
instance.category.add(validated_data.get('category', instance.category))
```